# How can i create a categories in Dart?

Tags: dictionary, dart

I've tried to create an app that creates categories and subcategories of some data from user's input. But, I'm stuck with duplicate output. Basically, I'm used Maps and functions to do that. I would like to know if it has a better way to do that and/or how i can fix that code.

Every time I add a category, subcategory or exercise it extends for others categories.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void newCategory(Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> category,
    Map<String, List<String>> subCategory) {
  stdout.write("Category name: ");
  final categoryName = stdin.readLineSync();
  category[categoryName] = subCategory;
}

void newSubCategory(Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> category,
    Map<String, List<String>> subCategory, List<String> exercise) {
  stdout.write("Category name: ");
  final categoryName = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (category.containsKey(categoryName)) {
    stdout.write("Subcategory name: ");
    final subCategoryName = stdin.readLineSync();
    subCategory[subCategoryName] = exercise;
  } else {
    print("Category invalid");
  }
}

void newExercise(Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> category,
    Map<String, List<String>> subCategory, List<String> exercise) {
  stdout.write("Category name: ");
  final categoryName = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (category.containsKey(categoryName)) {
    stdout.write("Subcategory name: ");
    final subCategoryName = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (subCategory.containsKey(subCategoryName)) {
      stdout.write("Exercise name: ");
      exercise.add(stdin.readLineSync());
    } else {
      print("Subcategory invalid");
    }
  } else {
    print("Category invalid");
  }
}

void showLibrary(Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> category) {
  category.forEach((key, value) => print("$key : $value"));
}

void main() {
  bool quit = true;

  final category = Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
  final subCategory = Map<String, List<String>>();
  final exercise = List<String>();
  while (quit) {
    print("""
    -- Library of Exercise --
    (1) add Category
    (2) add Subcategory
    (3) add Exercise
    (4) Show Library
    (5) Quit
    """);
    stdout.write("Digite um comando: ");
    const options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    final inputUser = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (options.contains(inputUser)) {
      switch (inputUser) {
        case "1":
          newCategory(category, subCategory);
          break;
        case "2":
          newSubCategory(category, subCategory, exercise);
          break;
        case "3":
          newExercise(category, subCategory, exercise);
          break;
        case "4":
          showLibrary(category);
          break;
        case "5":
          quit = false;
          break;
      }
    } else {
      print("Invalid command - try again");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you understand by walking you through the state of your program. Suppose I start the program and I give the following input:

```
1
Computer
2
Computer
Languages
```

Now if I give `4` as input I get:

```
Computer : {Languages: []}
```

Now think about `subCategory` variable and what value it holds.

It holds the latest sub-category that was input i.e. `Languages`

Now when you call `newCategory()`, you pass `subCategory` along, continuing our inputs:

```
1
Food
```

Now if I give `4` as input I get:

```
Computer : {Languages: []}
Food : {Languages: []}
```

This is expected since you passed `subCategory` to `newCategory()` and set sub-category there.

My suggestion for this problem would be to not pass `subCategory` since you're only creating a new category in `newCategory()` and no sub-categories of this new category are known yet. Same with passing `exercise` in `newSubCategory()`.